# Why is text sometimes presented BEFORE a picture, while it is supposed to be presented AFTERWARDS

Tags: floats

Why, in some instances, is the text **Here is some text** presented before the **picture.jpg** in the final document, please?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=...]{picture.jpg}
\caption{The best caption in the world.}
\end{figure}

Here is some text.
```

I have had similar problems when doing `\protect\footnotemark` inside the `\caption{...}`, when the `\footnotetext{...}` which is supposed to come afterwards, is presented before the image.

Comment: @jon I am not completely aware of what "floating" exactly encompasses in a LaTeX context, but I don't think I need that in any way for my purpose. So, I would be very glad if a solution could be given by circumventing the "floating".

Comment: Don't footnote a caption (in most circumstances). The caption is already a special kind of 'note', so footnoting a caption is rather like footnoting a footnote....

Comment: @jon The nice thing about the `figure` environoment is the automatic line-spacing after the figure.

Comment: They are in the answer below..? I'm afraid I can't guess what 'fiddled around with the `center` environment' means.

Comment: @jon True, it helps with the spacing, but the captions (I mean `\captionof`'s of course) are not centered along with the pictures. I mean: *in your MWE answer* they are, but when I encompassed `\captionof` inside `center` environment *in my document of purpose*, they weren't ( but aligned completely left sometimes, or a little to the left) ... I'll find the bug, I hope. Another bug (in my document of purpose) is that the `center` environment shifts some pictures to the right.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some minimal but self-contained and compilable code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: If it is in the `center` environment, just make a copy of your file, comment out all the text except for one or two paragraphs on either side of the `center` environment, and try to compile that. Then comment out packages that are clearly not related to uncommented text; then try to comment out the ones that probably aren't related; then try to comment out some more; etc., etc.

Comment: Hmm, that's simply not true in general (unless you have unclosed environments and so on). Doesn't the error message say why? Note that warnings are not errors. Are you loading other caption-related packages?

Comment: @jon Very strange: I found that deleting (or even just commenting out) the `\abstract{...}` (near the top of the document) fixes the issue of having horizontally shifted images almost all the way at the bottom of the document.

Comment: Good luck. I do wonder if it's due to some interaction between `capt-of` and another captioning package (in case you choose to explore further).

Comment: @jon I now reverted to original set-up (which solves the issue of the shifted images), and used `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` to stop floating. But, an issue I am having is that some (I'm using `hyperref`) footnotes don't link back to the original footnote-placing (inside an image's caption), but rather multiple pages early. EDIT: Now, some footnotes don't appear at all ...

Comment: Try adding `\phantomsection` before the `\footnotemark`, I guess. But I really must stress that  claiming 'phenomenon X happens' without the code that produces the effect is asking others to pull out crystal balls and call on the spirits to try to divine why X is happening. These are all legitimate questions, but you need to ask them *with* a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is probaly just to not let them 'float' via the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` environment. But one can also use the `\FloatBarrier` command from the `placeins` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mwe}% just for this example
\usepackage{capt-of}

% uncomment the \FloatBarrier to see it in action
\usepackage{placeins}
% Note you could load it as
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% this would include a \FloatBarrier in each use of \section

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Example Caption}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{The best caption in the world.}
\end{figure}

%\FloatBarrier
Here is some text.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{The best caption in the world.}
\end{figure}

%\FloatBarrier
Here is some text.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{The best caption in the world.}
\end{figure}

%\FloatBarrier
Here is some text.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{The best caption in the world.}
\end{figure}

%\FloatBarrier
Here is some text.

\end{document}
```